# Is there a way to use toFixed(N) inside handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I hava a template that uses `{{distance}}` and renders `1.473498223457834`...

Is there a way to format this directly within the template?

I tried with `{{distance.toFixed(2)}}` but it didn't work. The error was

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
...istance: {{distance.toFixed(2)}}</li><li
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
```

I tried to google it, but had no luck... that brought me to the idea that what I'm doing might be stupid. Is there a better way to format this kind of data? maybe directly within the model?

any best practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register an helper using `registerHelper` and use it for the conversion.

Code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('distanceFixed', function(distance) {
  return distance.toFixed(2);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/T7knB/